# Opencart stylesheet.css not updating

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, vqmod

I am using Opencart porto theme. But i am facing issue when i am updating stylesheet.css. Stylesheet.css effect appear on front end after an hour and more then an hour. That is too much frustrating for me. I have disable .htaccess file. disable vqmod. Clear browsers cache as well as cache in opencart. but not any effect. I have also checked extension there are no any cache extension found. Also i have checked path of stylesheet that is also fine because that effected after an hour.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

On a single System

CSS and JS files cache are saved in browser cache. You can force browser to reload all CSS and JS cache by pressing "CTRL + F5". By pressing this, all CSS and JS files reloaded again on browser and it takes more time to load.

On all customer's System

If you have a website that customers are using and you want to change the CSS in all customer's end. You can pass parameter in your CSS file.

Ex. Suppose you are using stylesheet.css in your header file, it should be included in header.tpl in common folder in your theme template folder as

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Whenever you make some changes in your CSS files, just change the parameter in header.tpl as

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css?version=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

since the file URL is changed, browser will have to reload this file on all customer's system. So your changes will appear on simple reload of web page.

Next time you change the stylesheet.css file, just modify header.tpl to

and so on.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to clear `vqcahche` in `vqmod` folder on root.

Comment: Cleared. but not effected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your file is saving properly after you upload it?

If you are using FileZilla there is a log on the top that says what is happening, check if you have an error for permission.

To debug it even further that you have the right stylesheet, make a backup and delete it, if nothing happens than this stylesheet is not the one you are looking for.

Also for further testing try putting some random CSS code in your header.tpl file to see if the issue is from caching or FTP access

Comment: CSS is fine because its effected after an hour.